# Orgmode-Spreadsheet: TBLFM-In-cell-calculation also possible with elisp code?

Tags: org-table, spreadsheet

Cell fields do automatic calculation by default.
For example

```
|-------+----------|
| Test  | Value    |
|-------+----------|
| Stone | 5.4+12.3 |
|-------+----------|
#+TBLFM: @>$>=@>$>
```

The cell formula refers to itself, the cell content is the calculation '5.4+12.3'.
Placing cursor on #+TBLFM line and pressing C-c C-c for re-applying the formulas to the entire table transforms cell content into the result '17.7'.

```
|-------+-------|
| Test  | Value |
|-------+-------|
| Stone |  17.7 |
|-------+-------|
[pointer]#+TBLFM: @>$>=@>$>
```

How awesome is that?!
The question now is: Can a `#+TBLFM` line with elisp code do the same?

Here are my attempts to reproduce it - in vain, all of which placing cursor on `#+TBLFM` line and pressing `C-c C-c` for re-applying the formulas to the entire table does NOT transform cell content into the result '17.7'.

#1 - with a bit transformation ahead ( ',' > '.'):

```
|-------+----------|
| Test  | Value    |
|-------+----------|
| Stone | 5,4+12,3 |
|-------+----------|
#+TBLFM: @>$>='(string-to-number (replace-regexp-in-string "," "." @>$>))
```

New cell content: 5.4

#2 - most basic approach:

```
|-------+----------|
| Test  | Value    |
|-------+----------|
| Stone | 5.4+12.3 |
|-------+----------|
#+TBLFM: @>$>='(string-to-number @>$>)
```

New cell content: 5.4

#3 - the sparking idea, that quick-calc must be behind it somehow:

3.1

```
|-------+----------|
| Test  | Value    |
|-------+----------|
| Stone | 5.4+12.3 |
|-------+----------|
#+TBLFM: @>$>='(quick-calc @>$>)
```

New cell content: `#ERROR`

3.2

```
|-------+----------|
| Test  | Value    |
|-------+----------|
| Stone | 5.4+12.3 |
|-------+----------|
#+TBLFM: @>$>='(calc-do-quick-calc @>$>)
```

New cell content: `#ERROR`

What does the trick? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
|-------+-------|
| Test  | Value |
|-------+-------|
| Stone |  17.7 |
|-------+-------|
#+TBLFM: @>$>='(calc-eval @>$>)
```

The point is that `@>$>` is (or is converted to) a string, so you need a function that takes a string and evaluates it, producing another string that can be assigned to the contents of the cell on the LHS.

`calc-eval` fits the bill: doing `C-h f calc-eval` says:

> (calc-eval STR &optional SEPARATOR &rest ARGS)
>
> Do a quick calculation and return the result as a string.
> Return value will either be the formatted result in string form,
> or a list containing a character position and an error message in string form.

The `quick-calc` idea was close, but `quick-calc` does not take a string as input (it reads it from the minibuffer) and it does not produce a string as its value (it prints it to the echo area). Note that `calc-eval` is part of the [Calc package](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html) which is what the Org mode table code uses to evaluate formulas ("normal" formulas, not `elisp` ones). Also note that there is no function named `calc-do-quick-calc` (try doing `C-h f calc-do-quick-calc`, so there was no hope that that would work.

Comment: SWEET! Works like a charm. Thank you very much, NickD, for giving both, the correct answer to the core question, and the fundamental background related to the core question. Couldn't have been answered better.

Comment: You are welcome!